# Rust way of initialize class field in constructor

Tags: rust

Take this example for init field class in ruby. I want to rewrite it in Rust. I manage to do it with the second snippet but I feel it's kinda weird to pass the self every time to access the struct field. Am I doing an anti-pattern? What is the better solution? Thanks a lot <333

```rb
class Workspace

  def initialize(pathname)
    @pathname = pathname
  end

  def list_files
    Dir.entries(@pathname)
  end
end
```

```rs
// implementation
pub struct Workspace {
  pathname: i32,
}

impl Workspace {
  pub fn new(pathname: i32) -> Self {
    Self { pathname }
  }

  pub fn list_files(self) {
    println!("{}", self.pathname);
  }
}
```

```rs
// pilot
   let workspace = Workspace::new(5);
   Workspace::list_files(workspace);
```

Comment: Your function definition is idiomatic (though I would imagine you may only want to borrow self), but the call can use method syntax: `workspace.list_files()`.

Comment: @eggyal you mean calling `workspace.list_files()` intead of `Workspace::list_files()`? that doesn't work if you mean that

Comment: Huh?  [Yes it does](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=aac7385fca6252daef6eee15290db2e4).

Comment: @eggyal yeah, you are right. thanks <333

Comment: if you want please submit the answer I can accept it. thanks again

Comment: Take @eggyal's advice though: borrow `self`, don't have just `self` there, or it's a move, and you might not be able to use `self` after that.  If everything in the struct is `Copy` you might be able to... but maybe not.  See [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#ways-variables-and-data-interact-move) in the manual for how structures move.

Comment: `.list_files(&self)` is what you want, not `.list_files(self)`. The second version consumes the `Workspace` instance; the former just borrows it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complement Zeppi's answer: having `self` be an explicit (but privileged) parameter is quite important in Rust because of borrowing: when you define `fn list_files(self)`, it can be called as:

```
workspace.list_file()
```

but the `self` (and thus the `workspace`) is *moved*, meaning it's consumed by the call and can't be used afterwards (try to call `list_file` a second time and you'll get an error).

To change the behaviour you have to indicate that the method doesn't *consume* the subject, which is done by annotating `self` with reference information e.g.

```
fn list_file(&self)
```

can be called the same way, but will only *borrow* `workspace` for the duration of the method call, and `workspace` remains usable afterwards.

There is also

```
fn list_file(&mut self)
```

which *updates* the workspace (and requires the variable to be defined as `let mut workspace = ...`).

So not only is this sort of "explicit self" quite common across the board, as Zeppi noted, it's actually quite critical to Rust<sup>[0]</sup>. It is also more natural when supporting [uniform function call syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.7.0/book/ufcs.html), which is exactly how you used it in your original post.

<sup>[0]</sup> technically the problem could be solved differently e.g. Swift has an implicit `self` and annotates the methods, however `&`/`&mut` annotations are standard in rust so reusing them makes a lot more sense than adding separate syntax for the same thing

Answer (score 2):

> feel it's kinda weird to pass the self every time

You have true, but this syntax existe also in other language like Golang, Perl or Python.

Rust is more purely functional programming and about the OOP concepte you can find more in the doc https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-00-oop.html.

Wath you write is globaly correct for me.

Or just this,  which would be more logical

```
fn main() {
   let workspace = Workspace::new(5);
   workspace.list_files();
}
```